# Passing "value" into provider using createContext in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I'm new to React JS and I'm trying to understand `createContext()` in functional components. So, here I'm trying to pass current state stored in `books` to the provider but I guess I'm doing something wrong. Could you please help me with this one?

Context Component:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const BookContext = createContext();
const BookContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([
    { title: "Book 1", id: 1 },
    { title: "Book 2", id: 2 },
    { title: "Book 3", id: 3 },
    { title: "Book 4", id: 4 },
  ]);

  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={ books }>  //<-- Doesn't work
      {props.children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default BookContextProvider;
```

Component where I want to use context:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { BookContext } from "../contexts/BookContext";

const BookList = () => {

  const { books } = useContext(BookContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {books.map((book) => (
          <li key={book.id}>
            {book.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the default value to your `createContext()`.